# I'm trouble in error of pandas "DataFrame"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a bigginer who are learning pandas.
I tried two things as follows, but I didn't solve it.
I use Jupyter notebook.
Could you please help me?

#1

```
import sys
sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

#2

```
from importlib import reload
import sys
reload(sys)
```

#I wanted to make it.
#I succeeded in it at another file, but it couldn't work at current file.

```
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
import pandas as pd

data={"ID":["001","002","003"],
      "city":["hyougo","tiba","gihu"],
      "people":["100","230","249"]}
data_frame=DataFrame(data)
print(data_frame)
```

#error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-133-640865466ed4> in <module>
          3       "people":["100","230","249"]}
          4 data_frame=DataFrame(data)
    ----> 5 print(data_frame)
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __repr__(self)
        678         else:
        679             width = None
    --> 680         self.to_string(
        681             buf=buf,
        682             max_rows=max_rows,
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in to_string(self, buf, columns, col_space, header, index, na_rep, formatters, float_format, sparsify, index_names, justify, max_rows, min_rows, max_cols, show_dimensions, decimal, line_width, max_colwidth, encoding)
        818                 line_width=line_width,
        819             )
    --> 820             return formatter.to_string(buf=buf, encoding=encoding)
        821 
        822     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in to_string(self, buf, encoding)
        912         encoding: Optional[str] = None,
        913     ) -> Optional[str]:
    --> 914         return self.get_result(buf=buf, encoding=encoding)
        915 
        916     def to_latex(
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in get_result(self, buf, encoding)
        519         """
        520         with self.get_buffer(buf, encoding=encoding) as f:
    --> 521             self.write_result(buf=f)
        522             if buf is None:
        523                 return f.getvalue()
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in write_result(self, buf)
        821         else:
        822 
    --> 823             strcols = self._to_str_columns()
        824             if self.line_width is None:  # no need to wrap around just print
        825                 # the whole frame
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in _to_str_columns(self)
        717         # may include levels names also
        718 
    --> 719         str_index = self._get_formatted_index(frame)
        720 
        721         if not is_list_like(self.header) and not self.header:
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in _get_formatted_index(self, frame)
       1057             )
       1058         else:
    -> 1059             fmt_index = [index.format(name=self.show_row_idx_names, formatter=fmt)]
       1060 
       1061         fmt_index = [
    
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `pandas` first and then add the alias `pd` before `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

data={"ID":["001","002","003"],
      "city":["hyougo","tiba","gihu"],
      "people":["100","230","249"]}
data_frame=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(data_frame)
```

Prints:

```
    ID    city people
0  001  hyougo    100
1  002    tiba    230
2  003    gihu    249
```

If you don't have pandas installed you will need to do that first

```
pip install pandas
```

Comment: Thank you for your advaise. I had already add "from pandas import Series,DataFrame
import pandas as pd". It didn't work. I'm sorry I was not clear.